# how to use map extension in siddhi

Tags: dictionary, siddhi

Here is my error when I use the map extension in my siddhi application:

> Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.query.compiler.exception.SiddhiParserException: Error between @ Line: 1. Position: 0 and @ Line: 1. Position: 150. Syntax error in SiddhiQL, no viable alternative at input 'map:create(1 , ?'.

And the `siddhi-execution-map` extension doc is in [here](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-execution-map/api/4.0.12/#create-function), and I don't know what can I do with this problem.

Can anyone tell me how to use it?

Comment: Can you share your siddhi app?

Comment: "define stream cseEventStream (ip string, port string,timestamp string);" +
            "@info(name = 'query1')" +
            "from cseEventStream#window.time(1 seconds)[port=='3301']" +
            "select map:create( a,1,b,2,c,3) as m insert into outputStream ;"

Answer (score 0):

From the siddhi app, it seems the map you are trying to create is statics, i.e string values would not change for each event, in that case, you use single quotes to wrap them,

> map:create( 'a',1,'b',2,'c',3)

Only the stream attribute can be defined without quotes,

> map:create('a', ip, 'b', port)